# Unable to slice along latitude and longitude in NetCDF satellite file (Xarray)

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

My data contains latitude and longitude values but I am unable to slice along them using Xarray. When I attempt to run code like this:

```
SeaIce[0].sel(latitude = slice(72,80))
```

I get the following error

```
ValueError: dimensions or multi-index levels ['latitude'] do not exist
```

But the dimensions do exist. Here's an example of one of the datasets I'm working with:

```
Dimensions:                                 (time: 1, xgrid: 304, ygrid: 448)
Coordinates:
  * time                                    (time) datetime64[ns] 2002-01-01
  * ygrid                                   (ygrid) float32 5.838e+06 ... -5....
  * xgrid                                   (xgrid) float32 -3.838e+06 ... 3....
    latitude                                (ygrid, xgrid) float64 31.1 ... 3...
    longitude                               (ygrid, xgrid) float64 168.3 ... ...
Data variables:
    projection                              |S1 b''
    seaice_conc_monthly_cdr                 (time, ygrid, xgrid) float32 0.0 ...
    stdev_of_seaice_conc_monthly_cdr        (time, ygrid, xgrid) float32 ...
    melt_onset_day_seaice_conc_monthly_cdr  (time, ygrid, xgrid) float32 ...
    qa_of_seaice_conc_monthly_cdr           (time, ygrid, xgrid) float32 ...
    goddard_merged_seaice_conc_monthly      (time, ygrid, xgrid) float32 ...
    goddard_nt_seaice_conc_monthly          (time, ygrid, xgrid) float32 ...
    goddard_bt_seaice_conc_monthly          (time, ygrid, xgrid) float32 ...
Attributes: (12/41)
    Conventions:               CF-1.6, ACDD-1.3
    title:                     NOAA/NSIDC Climate Data Record of Passive Micr...
    references:                Comiso, J. C., and F. Nishio. 2008. Trends in ...
    comment:                   The variable melt_onset_day_seaice_conc_monthl...
    program:                   NOAA Climate Data Record Program
    cdr_variable:              seaice_conc_monthly_cdr
                       ...
    history:                   seaice_conc_monthly_nh_f13_200201_v03r01.nc cr...
    platform:                  DMSP 5D-2/F13 > Defense Meteorological Satelli...
    sensor:                    SSM/I > Special Sensor Microwave/Imager
    date_created:              2017-11-27T02:44:53Z
    time_coverage_start:       2002-01-01T00:00:00Z
    time_coverage_end:         2002-01-31T23:59:59Z
```

I've tried slicing along the xgrid and ygrid dimensions, and those work, but naturally it's challenging to focus on the correct area without latitude and longitude dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around this using .where and a series of commands below:

```
dr = te.where((te.latitude > 72) & (te.latitude < 80) & (te.longitude > -15) & (te.longitude < 10),drop=True)
```

This selected the region bound by 72 to 80 latitude and -15 to 10 longitude.